# How to use Mac Camera on Ubuntu Desktop

Tags: ubuntu, video, camera

I am trying to feed my mac's camera into my ubuntu desktop. Any advice on either how to do this or the proper forum/resource to use to find out?

Comment: Hi! So you have an Apple camera (webcam?) that you would like to plug into and use on a Linux system, is that correct? It would be helpful if you could find what that device is called; that would also help searching for ways to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, there is no driver for Mac cameras. There is a kernel.org bug open [here](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=71131#c1), and a driver is under development (but not yet stable) [here](https://github.com/patjak/bcwc_pcie/).